# Не отображактся новое окно при RequestNavigation в Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Использую в приложении WPF и Prism c UnityContainer. Внутри приложения запускается отдельное окно со следующим содержимым:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
    <RadioButton Margin="5"
                 Command="{Binding AutoSchemeCommand}"
                 Content="Auto" />
    <RadioButton Margin="5"
                 Command="{Binding SingleSchemeCommand}"
                 Content="Individual" />
    <RadioButton Margin="5"
                 Command="{Binding SelectSchemeCommand}"
                 Content="Select from scheme" />
</StackPanel>
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="10,0"
                regions:RegionManager.RegionName="TypeSchemeRegion" />
```

То есть окно содержит регион, в котором по нажатию соответствующей RadioButton будет меняться содержимое. Для этого имеются соответствующие подокна и в стартовом модуле происходит их инициализация:

```
   RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TypeSchemeRegion", typeof(SchemeAutoView));
   RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TypeSchemeRegion", typeof(SchemeSingleView));
   RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TypeSchemeRegion", typeof(SchemeSelectView));
```

При открытии окна из программы исполняется следующий код:

```
var schemeView = unityContainer.Resolve<SchemeView>();

regionManager.Regions.Remove("TypeSchemeRegion");
RegionManager.SetRegionManager(schemeView, regionManager);
```

(SchemeView это самое запускаемое окно)
В этом месте все три подокна имеются в списке Views у региона, активным окном (ActiveView) является SchemeAutoView. При старте окна отображается содержимое подокна SchemeAutoView.
По нажатию соответствующей RadioButton исполняется код:

```
_regionManager?.RequestNavigate("TypeSchemeRegion", new Uri("SchemeSingleView", UriKind.Relative));
```

или:

```
_regionManager?.RequestNavigate("TypeSchemeRegion", new Uri("SchemeSelectView", UriKind.Relative));
```

Теперь, если проверить в Debuge содержимое региона, то активное окно соответственно меняется. Однако на экране ничего не происходит, по-прежнему отображается первое активное подокно. Для всех окон используется одна ViewModel.
Самое интересное, что в главном окне приложения (Shell) используется эта же методика и все работает на "ура", а в отдельном окне не хочет работать.
Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ошибку сам.
Оказывается при работе с Prism, если стартуешь внутри программы новое окно, которое, скажем так, не находиться в контексте главного окна (Shell), необходимо процедуру регистрации окон в регионах повторять почти так же, как в стартовом модуле. Ну или, по крайней мере, у меня так произошло.
Итак код при старте нового окна:

```
        regionManager.Regions.Remove("TypeSchemeRegion");
        var schemeView= unityContainer.Resolve<SchemeView>();
        RegionManager.SetRegionManager(schemeView, regionManager);
        RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TypeSchemeRegion", typeof(SchemeAutoView));
        RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TypeSchemeRegion", typeof(SchemeSingleView));
        RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TypeSchemeRegion", typeof(SchemeSelectView));
```

И еще очень важно сначала удалить необходимый регион, затем обязательно сделать Resolve соответствующего окна. В этот момент к окну привязывается ViewModel (если это необходимо) через Dependency Property, затем необходимо произвести переустановку RegionManager и новую привязку окон к региону.
Дальше в соответствующих местах RequestNavigate работает без проблем.